# Qual è il significato di "sciabolatore" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto questo testo su un ragazzo che lavora come "waterboy" in un cantiere dove si sta costruendo la ferrovia:

> Arrivato alla fine dei binari, scende, e prosegue a piedi, trascinando i secchi colmi d’acqua che bilancia con maestria sulle spalle. Non gli riesce difficile perché la gente di Tufo è capace di portare in equilibrio sulla testa qualunque cosa – un paniere pieno di uova, una balla di fieno, perfino una cassa da morto. Svuotare i secchi durante il tragitto non conviene perché il caposquadra, se pensa che fai il furbo, ti ammolla un papagno in faccia che ti sfigura. La fregatura è che gli **sciabolatori**, forse perché lavorano senza interruzione e solo quando bevono possono rifiatare, bevono come bufali, e prosciugano subito i secchi.

Qualcuno di voi mi potrebbe spiegare il significato di "sciabolatore" in questo brano? Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sciabolatore) ho trovato che questo termine significa

> Chi combatte con la sciabola; chi dà sciabolate; chi pratica la scherma nella specialità della sciabola.

Tuttavia, questa definizione non sembra avere molto senso nel passaggio sopra citato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tratta secondo me di un sinonimo di *spalatore*; ho trovato un riferimento in questo link: http://www.bdtorino.eu/sito/articolo.php?id=25313 dove viene spiegato che deriva da una storpiatura dell'inglese "shoveller" (appunto, spalatore, badilante).

Comment: Si tratterebbe quindi di un vocabolo italo-americano, no?

Comment: @Charo probabimente sì.

Comment: A conferma di quanto hai detto, nel libro [*Americana. Storie e culture degli Stati Uniti dalla A alla Z*](https://books.google.es/books?id=pNyvRS1vCrcC&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&dq=sciabola&source=bl&ots=itIlZkn8wu&sig=ACfU3U10To3h2Cn6zC9qn2mCXTgp_5blwA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwio_MLk7rfjAhUjSRUIHZXZB_sQ6AEwCHoECAYQAQ#q=sciabola&f=false) ho trovato un elenco di termini italo-americani tra i quali "sciabola" col significato di "badile" (dall'inglese "shovel"). Il "Re Erode" che appare nell'articolo che hai cirato sarebbe "railroad".

Answer (score 0):

Mio padre di 97 anni mi racconta che  suo suocero (mio nonno) aveva fatto lo sciabolatore in America, dove, con il termine di sciabolatore, si intendeva chi manovrava lo scambio dei binari in ferrovia.
Spero di essere stato utile.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Raffaele, e grazie della risposta.